# fetching required data using joins in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, having

My tables :

```
mysql> select * from professor;
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
| empid | name   | status | salary | age  |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
|     1 | Arun   |      1 |   2000 |   23 |
|     2 | Benoy  |      0 |   3000 |   25 |
|     3 | Chacko |      1 |   1000 |   36 |
|     4 | Divin  |      0 |   5000 |   32 |
|     5 | Edwin  |      1 |   2500 |   55 |
|     7 | George |      0 |   1500 |   46 |
+-------+--------+--------+--------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from works;
+----------+-------+---------+
| courseid | empid | classid |
+----------+-------+---------+
|        1 |     1 |      10 |
|        2 |     2 |       9 |
|        3 |     3 |       8 |
|        4 |     4 |      10 |
|        5 |     5 |       9 |
|        6 |     1 |       9 |
|        2 |     3 |      10 |
|        2 |     1 |       7 |
|        4 |     2 |       6 |
|        2 |     4 |       6 |
|        2 |     5 |       2 |
|        7 |     5 |       6 |
|        3 |     5 |       2 |
|        6 |     4 |      10 |
+----------+-------+---------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from course;
+----------+------------+--------+
| courseid | coursename | points |
+----------+------------+--------+
|        1 | Maths      |      5 |
|        2 | Science    |      1 |
|        3 | English    |      6 |
|        4 | Social     |      4 |
|        5 | Malayalam  |     20 |
|        6 | Arts       |     25 |
|        7 | Biology    |     20 |
+----------+------------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Question is :

> Return the name(s) of the professor(s) who taught the most number of
>   courses in Class 10

Query  i tried is :

```
select professor.name,works.courseid,works.empid,works.classid from professor
inner join works
on professor.empid=works.empid
where works.classid=10
group by works.courseid
```

I know its imcomplete/incorrect. Pls help me to the required result.

Comment: How do you know it's wrong? Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: your wished result is ?

Comment: Are you sure that *we* should be doing *your* homework?

Comment: Where is the professor table ? You showed us: works and course not professor ?

Comment: Where in your query do you do any counting of the number of courses taught?

Comment: @Kursion At the top of the question

Comment: @Barmar ahah ty scrolling problem ;)

Comment: Been there, done that (just a day or two ago).

Comment: Are you sure your "group by" is correct ? Shouldn't be on the name of the professor or the course ? group by professor.name ?

Comment: Like I said I am not sure about the query that I posted here. I am just a beginner. The result should 'Divin' as he is the professor who has taught most number of subjects in class 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
    professor.name, count(works.courseid)
from
    works
inner join
    professor on 
        professor.empid = works.empid 
where
    work.classid = 10
group by
    professor.name 
order by count(works.courseid) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Your query is almost rigth. But It shows all the professors name with their corresponding count of subject taught. I need to display only the one with the highest count

Comment: oh common. order by ... and limit 1

Comment: different DBMS uses different ways. with oracle you would have use the row number 1 from a outer table. with db2 fetch first 1 rows only.

Answer (score 0):

change this in your select statment

```
 works.courseid
```

to

```
count(works.courseid) as courseid
```

Comment: Sorry, I dont get you. whats that numberCourses?

Comment: @FrancisS this was just an alias, you can name it what you like. ok i change this name look update